# Where to put slideDown() in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add `slideDown('400')` in this javascript. But dont know where to put it.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                if (e.style.display == 'none')
                    e.style.display = 'block';
                else
                    e.style.display = 'none';
            }

        </script>
```

Iv'e tried this, but it does not work:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                if (e.style.display == 'none')
                    e.slideDown('400').style.display = 'block';
                else
                    e.style.display = 'none';
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: +! for showing effort and being clear, I don't know why you've received a downvote for this.

Comment: There is no JS function `slideDown`. You can't use that function on a DOM element. You should use the methods from the framework the `slideDown` function belongs to.

Comment: provide full code with jsfiddle.net , and ill help

Comment: `slideDown()` is a method of jQuery. Have you included it?

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes jQuery is included in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to keep inline with the syntax you already have, try this:

```
$(e).slideDown('400')...
```

Prior to the change above, you were attempting to call a jQuery function on a standard DOM element, it has no knowledge of what `slideDown` is as it's not a jQuery object.

NOTE: I would have a good read of the jQuery docs if I were you. Getting the element by ID in this way presents problems already solved by the jQuery library. It seems you're not fully embracing what it's capable of.

You could, instead, have:

```
var e = $('#' + id);
e.slideDown(400);
```